# Outlook global address book without To, Cc, Bcc options

Tags: c#, outlook

[image: Outlook Addressbook]

I'm working on a application where user names for text fields should be retrieved from outlook address book. So only one name can be selected at a time(There should not be To, Cc, Bcc options to select multiple recepients). I have done this for outlook 2003 using MAPI Interop.

how can i implement similar address book in outlook 2007 and 10 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following:

```
set SelectNames = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
SelectNames.SetDefaultDisplayMode(olDefaultSingleName)
SelectNames.Display
```